# Calling a private native method of DexFile

Tags: java-native-interface, native, dalvik

I want to call a method

> native private static int openDexFile(byte[] fileContents)

. I would like to know if it can be accessed by calling

> setAccessible(true)

on method before invoking it and will it work the same way as using JNI to access a native method?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?  Are you sure you can't accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do with published API methods?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do this with the reflection API.  How the method is called should be the same.

Comment: Every method in the dex can be invoked by reflecting if you set the access by API: `setAccessible(true)`